# Sec-Websocket-Protocol issues

Tags: go, websocket, protocols, gorilla

I am facing an issue with Go while using the WebSockets protocol. If I connect to my API, everything works fine. If I add "protocol" such as "Hey", it begins to loop multiple times and finishes by getting an error `*github.com/gorilla/websocket.CloseError`: "Code 1006, Text Unexpected EOF".

I definitely don't get why it acts like this when I send `Sec-Websocket-Protocol` among the connection.

There is my code:

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/golang/glog"
    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime"
    stacktracer "gitlab.com/eyes-eyes/internals-stacktracer"
    "gitlab.com/eyesbank/go-web-sockets-server/handlers"
    "net/http"
)

const webSocketsAddr = "0.0.0.0:8082"

// main is the starting point of the current micro service.
func main() {

    // Setting the service name
    stacktracer.SetServiceName("Hello 'X' (Web Sockets)")

    // Initializing the HTTP errors handling
    runtime.HTTPError = stacktracer.DefaultHTTPError

    if err := RunWebSocketsServer(); err != nil {
        glog.Fatal(err)
    }

}

//
// WebSocket
//

func RunWebSocketsServer() error {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        handlers.HandleUserSocket(w, r)
    })

    fmt.Println(webSocketsAddr)

    return http.ListenAndServe(webSocketsAddr, nil)
}

func RunWebSocketsTLSServer() error {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        handlers.HandleUserSocket(w, r)
    })

    fmt.Println(webSocketsAddr)

    return http.ListenAndServeTLS(webSocketsAddr, "server.crt", "server.key", nil)
}
```

`handler.go`

```
package handlers

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    stacktracer "gitlab.com/eyes-eyes/internals-stacktracer"
    "gitlab.com/eyes-eyes/internals-stacktracer/structs"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}

func HandleUserSocket(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var userID = primitive.NewObjectID()
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil) // error ignored for sake of simplicity
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    } else {
        WriteOutgoingMessage(conn, "Welcome "+userID.Hex())
    }

    fmt.Println(r.Header["Sec-Websocket-Protocol"])
    if len(r.Header["Sec-Websocket-Protocol"]) > 0 {
        WriteOutgoingMessage(conn, userID.Hex() + " " + string(r.Header["Sec-Websocket-Protocol"][0]))
    }

    for {
        // Read message from browser
        _, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            if err != nil {
                switch err.(type) {
                case *websocket.CloseError:
                    fmt.Println("disconnected")
                    return
                default:
                    _ = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
                    fmt.Println(err.Error())
                    fmt.Println("disconnected")
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        if msg != nil {
            WriteOutgoingMessage(conn, userID.Hex() + " " + string(msg))
        }
    }
}

func WriteOutgoingMessage(conn *websocket.Conn, message string) *structs.StackTrace {

    // Write message back to browser
    if err := conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Got: \""+message+"\"")); err != nil {
        err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        if err != nil {
            return stacktracer.NewStackTrace(500, err.Error(), nil)
        }
    }

    return nil

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a client requests subprotocols and the server does not agree to one of those subprotocols, then the client is required to close the connection. A client uses the Sec-Websocket-Protocol header to request one or more subprotocols. A server uses the Sec-Websocket-Protocol response header to agree to a protocol.  the See the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.9) for more on this topic.

Fix the problem by agreeing to one of the protocols requested by the client. There are a couple of ways to do this.

The first is to use the built-in protocol negotiation feature:

```
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    Subprotocols: []string{ "hey" },  // <-- add this line
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}
```

The second is to negotiate the protocol in application code before the call to Upgrade.  Call [websocket.Subprotocols](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Subprotocols) to get the requested protocols, select one of the protocols and specify that protocol in the header argument to Upgrade.

```
h := http.Header{}
for _, sub := range websocket.Subprotocols(req) {
   if sub == "hey" {
      h.Set("Sec-Websocket-Protocol", "hey")
      break
   }
}
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, h)
```

Separate from this issue, the application should `defer conn.Close()` after successful upgrade.

Also, the error handling logic can be simplified. The application should exit the read loop on any error returned from ReadMessage. There's no point in writing a message after the connection errors. The ReadMessage method returns a non-nil message on success.

```
for {
    // Read message from browser
    _, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Println(err.Error())
          fmt.Println("disconnected")
          return
    }
    WriteOutgoingMessage(conn, userID.Hex() + " " + string(msg))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However, if I have to accept the « protocol », how do I manage to make this one as a token? Because I would like hey to be replaced by my token or something as ‘auth:token’

Comment: @Emixam23 Write application code to negotiate the protocol by selecting whatever value is in the Sec-Websocket-Protocol request header (example: `h := http.Header{"Sec-Websocket-Protocol": req.Header["Sec-Websocket-Protocol"]} )`  Note that the subprotocol name must be a valid [RFC 2616 token](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).  The value `auth:token` is not an a valid RFC 2616 token because it contains a ":".

Comment: ALright ! it took me some time to understand from your answer but I could make it work as expected. When you add protocols from client side, if one of them is present in the upgrader, then it doesn't automatically close the connection :) Thanks again